# Making HTTP requests from within MongoDB Atlas App Services

Tags: mongodb, http, mongodb-atlas

We are currently using the [Third-party HTTP Service](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/services/http/) provided by MongoDB in order to make HTTP requests to the outside world from within our app running in [Atlas App Services](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/). As per their documentation, this will be deprecated in December 2022.

However, I can't find an alternative for the future - what will be the preferred way to make HTTP requests from within Atlas App Services Apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in similar situation before as you are.
But then I realised that App Service team actually simplifies it by adding support for dependencies.

So, I can import standard axios library and starts using it seamlessly as

```
exports = async function(arg){
  const axios = require('axios'); // is allowed here

  axios.get('https://coderower.com')
    .then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  
  
  return {success: true}
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ishaan, this was the solution. One caveat that took me a while to figure out was that "require" isn't allowed at the top level - would you mind editing your answer to make this more clear to readers?

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2023. Axios ONLY works with `1.0.0-alpha.1`. Most other versions will throw import errors.

Comment: @RoguePanda As of 04/22/2023, axios 1.2.0 works in Atlas functions.